# Where is cat command stored in linux?

Tags: cat

I have visited usr/bin directory, but there's no file called cat. How can I find where cat file is stored? I also used Linux global search which did not work.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ whereis -b cat
cat: /usr/bin/cat
```

```
$ command -v cat
/usr/bin/cat
```

```
$ type cat
cat is hashed (/usr/bin/cat)
```

---

(not advised)

```
$ which cat
/usr/bin/cat
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then#85250